# GET http://localhost:3000/api/products/sofa-happy-2-cho-va-2-armchair-vai 404 (Not Found) AxiosError

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, nextjs-dynamic-routing

when I click a Product, I want to show product details. However, when I clicked a product, It appeared **the error: GET http://localhost:3000/api/products/sofa-happy-2-cho-va-2-armchair-vai 404 (Not Found) AxiosError**
When I saw this error, I thought I made api end point wrong, then I checked again and my api end point was right. Then I thought maybe the slug I wanted to get wrong, I console.log slug and it didnt wrong. I also checked the function in getProductDetail and it's normal. Please help me, I dont know where I was wrong. This is my code

I made an api route like this **api/products/[slug]/route.js** and code inside like this:

```
import { connect } from '@/backend/config/mongodb'
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server"
import Product from '@/backend/models/Product'

connect()

export async function GET(req) {
    try {
        const product = await Product.find({ slug: req.query.slug })
        if (!product) {
            return NextResponse.json(
                { error: "Product not found!" },
                { status: 404 }
            )
        }
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: true,
            product
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 })
    }
}
```

Then I made a ProductDetails page like this **(routes)/products/[slug]/page.jsx**

```
'use client'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ProductDetail from '../../../components/product/ProductDetail'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Product({ params }) {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getProductDetails = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/products/${params.slug}`)
                setProduct(data.product)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

        getProductDetails()
    }, [params.slug])

    return (
        <div>
            <ProductDetail product={product} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

In ProductDetail page I console.log the product props and it return an empty array

Please help me find the error. I'm using NEXTJS

I want to fix this error

Comment: What exactly is the filename and path of your [route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)? It should be `app/api/products/[slug]/route.js`

Comment: I fixes the filename and path of my route handler, but I still have that error

Comment: So does the request hit your route handler at all? You could add `console.log('looking up product', req.query.slug)` to make sure. If it is, then it seems simply that there is no product matching the slug you're requesting

Comment: The req.query.slug that I console.log equal with the params.slug too

Comment: So it is hitting your route handler? Seems obvious that there's no matching slug in your DB then

Comment: if slug in my DB is sofa-bolero-3-cho-+-djon-m3-vai-xanh-mb408 and the slug of params.slug and req.query.slug is sofa-bolero-3-cho-%2B-djon-m3-vai-xanh-mb408, is it not equal right? Because I can see the + sign in slugDB tranfers to %2B in params.slug and req.query.slug

Comment: Sounds like there might be some double encoding going on somewhere. When you `console.log()` the value, it should show `+`, not `%2B`. What is the URL in your browser when you open the page?

Comment: my URL in your browser when you open the page is http://localhost:3000/products/sofa-bolero-3-cho-+-djon-m3-vai-xanh-mb408

Comment: the error is page.jsx:11 
 GET http://localhost:3000/api/products/sofa-bolero-3-cho-%2B-djon-m3-vai-xanh-mb408 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question so the formatting is clear. Also, you initially said it was a 404 error. If you're getting a 500 now, perhaps you should log the error in your route handler... `console.error('Error finding product by slug', req.query.slug, error)`

Comment: @klng please share you project folder structure.